# Formik Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, formik

**Formik**

I am new to formik and start using it every time i start learning i got this issue

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

I am unable to locate error cause this is my code 
// here is Login.js file

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
    import validator from "validator";
    import { withFormik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
    import Yup from 'yup';
    import { RingLoader } from "react-spinners";
    import "./Login.css";
    import logo from "../../img/logo.png";
    var NotificationSystem = require("react-notification-system");


    class Login extends Component {

      render() {

        let { errors, touched } = this.props;

        console.log("Login Component",this.props);
        return (
          <div className="content">
            <Row>
              <Col md={4} mdOffset={4} xs={10} xsOffset={1}>
                <div style={stylelogobox}>
                  <img src={logo} style={logoStyle} />
                </div>
                <Form className="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <legend className="text-center">
            <h2>Login</h2>
          </legend>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div className="col-lg-10">
              <Field
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="username"
                name="username"
              />
              {errors.username && touched.username && errors.username}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-lg-2 control-label">
              Password
            </label>
            <div className="col-lg-10">
              <Field
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                name="password"
              />
              {errors.password && touched.password && errors.password}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <Col lg={10} lgOffset={2}>
              <button
                // disabled={this.props.user.isLogging}
                className="btn btn-primary login-button btn-block LoginButton"
                // disabled={this.state.isEnabled}
                // onClick={this.handlesOnLogin}
              >
                <span> Login </span>
              </button>
            </Col>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </Form>

              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col md={4} mdOffset={4} xs={10} xsOffset={1}>
                <div className="pull-right">
                  <Button bsStyle="default" onClick={this.goForgetPassword}>
                    Password Reset
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <div className="sweet-loading loadingSpinner">
              <RingLoader
                color={"#5c1a3e"}
                //loading={this.state.loading}
                loading={this.props.user.isLogging}
              />
            </div>

            <div>
              <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }




const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  initialValues: { username: "", password: "" },
  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 400);
  }
});

export default formikEnhancer(Login);
```

I am importing this file to index.js where i am connecting this to redux store. index.js and login.js are in same folder

here is Index.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Login from "./Login";


import {
  login,
  loginRequestLoader,
  resetInvaliduser
} from "../../redux/actions/user";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {

    user: state.user,
    loginFlag: state.user.login
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loginRequestLoader: () => dispatch(loginRequestLoader()),
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password)),
    resetInvaliduser: () => dispatch(resetInvaliduser())
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

here is Import from index.js file into Routes file

```
import Login                    from './views/login/index';
```

i don't know why this is getting the error i have tries withFormik and also Formik component but nothing work i also tries to see props in Login component using console log but it is also not logging the props means nothing is log.

Comment: ?? As you said, it is async ... You're returning much earlier than the async code has been finished and the results are available.

Comment: show your imports too

Comment: Updated the code and <Formik /> is in render method of Login Component

Comment: what if you remove whole `fieldset` element with its children from LoginForm, do you still get error?

Comment: Yes, i have removed fieldset element, but get same error

Comment: show all the imports in LoginForm

Comment: Import added see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic error caused by issues with imports. However, from my tests with `react@16`, it looks like any version below `react-dom@16.4` will show this specific error where the element is imported as an object.

This CodeSandbox demonstrates the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/0vrn83o6ww
(Change the react/react-dom versions to test your environment)

**If you're using `react@16`, update `react-dom` to a version `>=16.4` and this should fix the error.**

Recent versions `formik` with incompatible versions of `react-dom` have made this error come up: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/907

Answer (score 1):

This issue can also be seen at newer version of `formik` and `react-dom`. It can be caused by mocking the `useFormikContext` hook, even if supplying a mocked response.

In my case, letting Formik do its thing, without mocking anything, got rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

As @brettinternet said, it's generic, and common. Could be that when using `export default formikEnhancer(Login)`, then you need to import it like a non-default class:

```
import {Login} from './Login';
```

For other folks searching, it's also happens when you entirely forget to define your component's default export.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and the problem was a particular component inside Formik, that at the time was just an empty jsx file. I resolved by fixing the component properly. Formik was just warning "there is something wrong inside the Formik tag, friend".

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.