# Element type is invalid: React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.` when I use the following code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './App';
import { authConfig } from './auth/authconfig';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const store = configureStore(history, window.initialReduxState);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

console.log('init');
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  </Layout>
);
```

Changing `<App />` to `<p>test</p>` make it work so I guess the problem is in App.js, but am not sure what's wrong there.

<s>Also, when I use these code in the client app of .NET Core React-Redux template it works well, that makes me further confused.</s> What do I need to resolve this and how can I find the issue if this information is not enough?

**EDIT**

I didn't remember that I substituted react-bootstrap in .net core template to reactstrap, so the problem was in the NavMenu.js as @devserkan pointed out.

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';

export default props => (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col sm="12" lg={{ size: 10, offset: 1 }}>
        <NavMenu />
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col sm="12" lg={{ size: 10, offset: 1 }}>
        {props.children}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
```

**NavMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem } from 'reactstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default props => (
  <StyledNavbar inverse fixedTop fluid collapseOnSelect>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Link to={'/'}>HogeHoge</Link>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav>
        <NavItem href="/counter">Counter</NavItem>
        <NavItem href="/fetchdata">Fetch data</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </StyledNavbar>
);

//Styled Components
const StyledNavbar = styled(Navbar)`
  .navbar-nav .active a,
  .navbar-nav .active a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .active a:focus {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #4189c7;
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Can you show us the Layout/Home component?

Comment: Alright, edited.

Comment: Which version of `reactstrap` is this? There isn't any use of `Navbar.Brand` and etc. There is `NavbarBrand` and it is exported separately from `reactstrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your usage of `Navbar.Brand` etc. to `NavbarBrand` since there is not any export from `Navbar` as `Brand` and etc. There are separate exports as `NavbarBrand` from `reactstrap` itself as can be seen [here](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/index.js).

**Update after comments**

As far as I know `ConnectedRouter` is coming with `connected-react-router`
 now :)

Comment: I think you figured it out somehow :) But, I've updated my answer.

Comment: You got the point. I didn't remember that I substituted react-bootstrap in .net core template to reactstrap. I added an edit to the post. Now the error was gone and I only have You should not use <Route/Link> outside a <Router> and I'll figure out the problem there. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh I deleted the comment and update it while you're updating the post and comment... `connected-react-router` solves the problem but made another one `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`. I'll go on this one next and post a new question if it's not solved.

Answer (score 3):

This is commonly a generic error for incorrectly imported modules. This could be an issue with your child components in `Layout.js` or `Home.js`. Make sure you're importing the modules correctly.

```js
import {MyComponent} from '../components/xyz.js'; // throws error if not default export
```

vs

```js
import MyComponent from '../components/xyz.js'; // works!
```

---

I've also seen a similar error with a library I was using.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52432243/6817437

It might help if you can recreate your error in a codesandbox.io to narrow down the exact issue.

---

Side note: using anonymous functions to construct React functional components is bad practice. Implicit naming is O.K. with arrow functions ([see Dan's tweet here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/838391949975564288)). Anonymous functions are harder to test and debug components when they don't have a display name.

Comment: Well, I made it work by just replacing the exported component of Layout.js and navMenu.js by pure <div>s. I'm now going to find the wrong importing.

Comment: And also did you mean in your side note that I should always use `export default function hogehoge(props)...`?